# How do I get the value of an Observable in a service from a component and pass it to my view?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I've tried many things for this, and nothing seems to help.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

1. User clicks button on Selection component view
2. Event fires, calling `changePage()` on the selection component
3. This calls `changePage()` on the service and passes in a string
4. `changePage()` in the service updates an `observable`
5. In the main component, a `subscription` is created and changes the variable `pageName`'s value based on the `Observable` in the service
6. The `pageName` is updated as a header on the page

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class PageService{
    pageChange$: Subject<String> = new BehaviorSubject("About Me");

    constructor(){
    }

    public changePage(changeTo: String){
        console.log(changeTo); // LOGS PROPERLY
        this.pageChange$.next(changeTo);
    }
}
```

**Selection Component**

```
export class SelectionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _pageService:PageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  // Called on button click, passed a string from the button
  changePage(changeTo: string){
      this._pageService.changePage(changeTo);
  }
}
```

**Main Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PageService } from '../page-service.service';
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-content',
  templateUrl: './main-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-content.component.css'],
  providers: [PageService]
})
export class MainContentComponent implements OnInit {    
  pageName: String;

  constructor(private _pageService: PageService) {  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this._pageService.pageChange$.subscribe(value => {
          console.log(value); // DOES NOT LOG
          this.pageName = value;
      });
}
```

**Information to update**

```
<h3 class="content-header">{{ pageName }}</h3>
```

I've been struggling with this for a while. Admittedly I'm pretty new to Angular, and maybe I'm just confused on how Observables work, but currently it's not working.

I am getting a single console.log in the console with "About Me", but nothing after that. No errors, nothing. The h3 DOES say About Me, but does not change.

Comment: Can we see the binding in the template (where you perform the click)?

Comment: I'm not near my PC right now but it's (click)="changePage('button value')"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Main component i noticed that you are providing your PageService like this

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [PageService]
})
```

If you are also doing the same in your Selection Component you wont be able to get the emitted message. This is cause by how Angular's Dependency Injection works. You need to have a Singleton PageService between your Main Component and your Selection Component. If that's the case, you should remove  `providers: [PageService]` from both components and **only** provide it in your root module. (in most cases `app.module.ts`).

Try that and see if you wont get the emitted message from PageComponent in your MainComponent.

**Edit**

You can read more about DI [here.](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/di/what_is_di.html)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I hadn't even thought of that, and that seems to have worked. It looks like my issue was that my structure was the main component and selection component as siblings with the PageService being added as providers to both. After removing it from both as providers and adding it to the providers list in the parent element (app-component), it works perfectly!